# The margins in div of new tab not at all taking effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am creating dynamic form in new tab using JavaScript. Margin effects on div are not taking effect. I am neither able to set the margins using class and id in css nor using div.setAttribute. Below is the code.
`

```
var openWindow = window.open('dynForm.html','_blank','');
    var windoc=openWindow.document;
    windoc.write("This is dynamic form ");
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("style","border:solid");
    div.setAttribute("style","margin-left:1cm");
    div.setAttribute("style","margin-right:1cm");
    div.setAttribute("style","margin-bottom:1cm");
    div.setAttribute("style","margin-top:1cm");
    div.setAttribute("style","background-color:lightblue");
```

`Only background color is taking effect on the new tab. The below screen shot shows how the screen looks irrespective of the values of margin.[image]

***Quesstion 2***: No class or id attribute in my css is being applied to div.

```
    #myDIV2{

    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

I tried `div.id="myDIV2";`

I also tried `div.setAttribute("id","myDIV2")`;` I applied the same using class also, but still couldn't find any difference. I do not know why its not working and what went wrong here. Please help

Comment: I'd imagine because you're overriding the entire `style` attribute every time you call `div.setAttribute`. So only the last effect is applied. You might need a way to compound them.

Comment: How should I modify my code to get what I want. Also can you please tell me why is #myDIV2 not taking effect on the div in new tab. I comment all setAttribute lines before adding #myDIV2. This is my second Question. All I wanted to know is how to add a class from css file to my div element in new tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overriding the styles every time you call setAttribute, try combining the styles and then set the style attribute only once:

```js
var openWindow = window.open('dynForm.html','_blank','');
    var styles= [
      "border:solid;",
      "margin: 1cm;",
      "background-color:lightblue;"
    ];
    var windoc=openWindow.document;
    windoc.write("This is dynamic form ");
    var end_styles = "";
    for (var i=0; i<styles.length;i++) {
        end_styles += styles[i];
    }
    var div=document.createElement("div");
    div.setAttribute("style", end_styles);
```

Note: the fiddle won't work on stackoverflow, I used it because it's easier to format code

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your all style attribute are getting overridden by previous `div.setAttribute` and your last attribute `div.setAttribute("style","background-color:lightblue");` getting applied. Try to put all styles in one go. `div.setAttribute("style","style1:value1;style2:value2;style3:value3;");`

Comment: Thanks Tharun, Can you please answer for my second question also on how to add #myDIV2 to my div element.

Comment: Usually, `div.id` or `setAttribute` should work. Can you create a fiddle?